# servicestack.redis getvalues gives junk values

Tags: servicestack.redis

I am facing an issue getting junk values like 'OK' or '0' or some 'numeric' values while reading values from Redis. This happens while reading normal key and hash keys as well. We have upgraded all the service stack components and still facing the issues. Please find the component details and the code snippet in c#

Our environment: We have setup sentinel, and each sentinel is paired with a Redis instance. Now we have setup three instances of sentinel and three instances of redis server. We were using read only client for reading values and read-write client for writing values to Redis. Even after using read-write client for reading and writing is also giving the same junk value problems.

```
 Components:
    ServiceStack.Common v 5.1.0.0
    ServiceStack.Redis v 5.1.0.0
    ServiceStack.Interfaces v 5.1.0.0
    ServiceStack.Text v 5.1.0.0

    Redis server v 3.0.503

    OS: Windows server 2012 R2
```

code snippet:

```
private static IredisClientManager m_redisManager;
initializeRedis()
{
    if(m_redisManager == null)
     {
          var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(
          "193.168.1.1:16380,193.168.1.2:16380,193.168.1.3:16380"
          ,"testmaster")
          {
              RefreshSentinelHostsAfter = 10;
          };
          sentinel.RedisManagerFactory += (master,slaves) 
                     => new RedisManagerPool(master);
          m_redisManager = sentinel.Start();
     }
}

public string GetValue(string key)
{
    string val;
    using(var client = m_redisManager.GetClient())
    {
       val = client.GetValue(key);
    }
    return val;
}

Note:
```

1. m_redisManager is declared as static, so that it runs only once. Each call will share this manager
2. client is disposing after each call to get value
3. My application is a multi threaded, so reading from multiple thread may happen at the same time. And application is muti instancing from same machine and difeerent machine as well.
4. The above code is from component which interact with Redis.
5. Client will call GetValue function

What could be the problem? Can someone help

Comment: Can you add more code to reflect the expected data? As it is right now, the code sample doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Abhinav, Added more codes and description, please check it